# Finding the amount of numbers within an array within a specific range using recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I've been stuck on a recursion assignment for hours now.
Basically its recursion practice and I completed everything except one thing:

**Find the amount of numbers in range within an array.**

I have to use recursion, and pointers of the array. So far I've done find the sum of array and find if the array HAS the numbers within range. No problem.
BUT, now I have to find how many occurences within the range it is. I can do it with a loop and using a "counter index" variable, but I must use recursion.
I can't seem to get it to work.
**Right now my attempt is this:**

```
int numberOfValuesInRange(float min, float max, const float *pBegin, const float *pEnd){

     if(pBegin >= pEnd) // base case
         return 0;
     if (min+max - *pBegin >= min+max)

         return 0 + numberOfValuesInRange(min, max, pBegin, pEnd);

}
```

I get nothing.
And below is the other bits of code for sum and a bool if it has numbers in range.

Sum of array.

```
float sum(const float *pBegin, const float *pEnd){  //Adds all elements in array of float numbers and returns their sum
    if (pBegin >= pEnd)
        return 0;
    return *pBegin + sum(pBegin+1, pEnd);
}
```

And check if array has values in range:

```
bool hasValueInRange(float min, float max, const float *pBegin, const float *pEnd){ //Checks if array elements are within min/max range

    if(pEnd > pBegin && *pBegin <= max && *pBegin >= min){
        cout << "Array DOES contain values in range " << endl;
        return true;}
        else{
            cout << endl << "Array does NOT contain values in range " << endl;
            return false;
        }
}
```

Here is my main function (If it helps):

```
int main(){
    const int size = 5;
    float sampleArray[5] = {2, 4, 6, 0, 1};
 sum(&sampleArray[0], &sampleArray[size])
hasValueInRange(0, 5, &sampleArray[0], &sampleArray[size]); //Checks for values between 0 and 5
        int x = 0;
        x = numberOfValuesInRange(2,5, &sampleArray[0], &sampleArray[size]); //Occurences within range 2 to 5
    cout << x; // Should be 2
return 0;
```

Any help would be lovely, thanks!
I know its just one piece of the puzzle missing...

Comment: `min+max - *pBegin >= min+max`: For which values of `*pBegin` do you expect this to be true?

Comment: `return 0 +`: Do you really want to add `0` to the count if you found a match?

Comment: `numberOfValuesInRange(min, max, pBegin, pEnd)`: You are calling the next recursion step with the _exact same_ arguments as the current one. Is that really what you want? Look at your other example. Did you simply pass the same arguments to the recursion step there?

Comment: Please tell us about your observations, when you stepped through your code line by line with the debugger.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the number is in range add one

```
if ((*pBegin) >= min && (*pBegin) <= max)
            return 1 + numberOfValuesInRange(min, max, pBegin+1, pEnd);
```

### Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int numberOfValuesInRange(float min, float max, const float *pBegin, const float *pEnd){

    if(pBegin >= pEnd) // base case
        return 0;
    //if (min+max - *pBegin >= min+max)
    //  return 0 + numberOfValuesInRange(min, max, pBegin, pEnd);
    if ((*pBegin) >= min && (*pBegin) <= max)
        return 1 + numberOfValuesInRange(min, max, pBegin+1, pEnd);

    return numberOfValuesInRange(min, max, pBegin+1, pEnd);

}

float sum(const float *pBegin, const float *pEnd){  //Adds all elements in array of float numbers and returns their sum
    if (pBegin >= pEnd)
        return 0;
    return *pBegin + sum(pBegin+1, pEnd);
}

bool hasValueInRange(float min, float max, const float *pBegin, const float *pEnd){ //Checks if array elements are within min/max range

    if(pEnd > pBegin && *pBegin <= max && *pBegin >= min){
        cout << "Array DOES contain values in range " << endl;
        return true;}
    else{
        cout << endl << "Array does NOT contain values in range " << endl;
        return false;
    }
}

int main(){
    const int size = 5;
    float sampleArray[5] = {2, 4, 6, 0, 1};
    cout<<sum(&sampleArray[0], &sampleArray[size])<<endl;
    hasValueInRange(0, 5, &sampleArray[0], &sampleArray[size]); //Checks for values between 0 and 5
    int x = 0;
    x = numberOfValuesInRange(2,5, &sampleArray[0], &sampleArray[size]); //Occurences within range 2 to 5
    cout <<x<<endl; // Should be 2
    return 0;
}
```

### Output :

```
$ g++ recurssion.cpp && ./a.out
13
Array DOES contain values in range 
2
```